# Python2.7 - reading from tempfile

Tags: python, python-2.7, temporary-files, temp

I use python2.7 and i have a question about reading from tempfile. Here is my code:

```
import tempfile


for i in range(0,10):
    f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

    f.write("Hello")

    ##f.seek(0)

    print f.read()
```

With this code , i get something like this:

```
Rﾜ
nize.pyR
ﾞ`Sc
d
Rﾜ
Rﾜ
Z
Z
nize.pyR
ﾞ`Sc
```

what are these?

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Do you perhaps have a file named `tempfile.py` in the same directory as your script?

Comment: cannot reproduce on mac, but I get similar results on windows

Answer (score 1):

You are writing string to a file opened in bytes mode.  Add the mode parameter to your call to NamedTemporaryFile:

```
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w")
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: if I do this in code then displays an error :
`IOError: File not open for reading`..
There is something i dont understand?